# Custom post type slug as page slug

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have a custom page type `dictionary` and all of the dictionary items have URLs like this: `example.com/dictionary/item`

*dictionary has `has_archive => false`*

The problem occurs if I also create a page called Dictionary with an URL `example.com/dictionary`

Now, all of the dictionary item pages are giving me an 404 error.

CPT was created using CPT UI

---

So, my question is: how to make it so that `example.com/dictionary` would show a page called "Dictionary" (not an archive) and that all of the items would show on their URLs, example: `example.com/dictionary/item-1` and not show a 404 error instead.

I refreshed permalinks by going settings -> permalinks, and hitting save.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have you flushed the permalink rules?

Comment: updated the question. BTW the page is: https://reflectivedata.com/analytics-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

flush your permalinks.  Go to settings / permalinks and hit save.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately that didn't help. The page is: https://reflectivedata.com/analytics-dictionary

Comment: that's not /dictionary as a page.  I tried going to /dictionary and it takes me back to that page though.  does the site load as normal without 404 when you disable cpt ui?

Comment: yeah, sorry, on real site dictionary is actually analytics-dictionary (just shortened it in the question). But disabling cpt ui didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more thing is possible. When you register the custom post type, you can use additional `rewrite` `with_front` argument:

```
$args = array(
    // ( ... your arguments here ... )
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'dictionary',
        'with_front' => false // notice here
    ),
    // ( ... more arguments here ... )
```

This will remove the CPT base (`dictionary` in your case) from the URL.

And don't forget to flush permalinks each time you change the code relative to them.

[See `rewrite` in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#rewrite).

Comment: That's not what with_front does, it controls whether any prefix on the built in post type gets added to cpt urls.